# Disabling a textbox if it has value and ignored this disabled value in addition and subtraction in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add id= lr1, lr2 & lr3 total will show in id=tlrr and subtract from id=totalAmt.

HTML CODE.

```
<tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Receiving Quarantine </b></td>
      <td>
        <input type="textbox" name="rcv_quantity" class="tqty" id="totalAmt"  value="<?php echo $row->rcv_quantity; ?>" />  </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-1 </b></td>
      <td>
         <input type="textbox" name="lot_rel1" id="lr1" class="lr" value="<?php echo $row->lot_rel1; ?>" />   </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-2 </b></td>
      <td>
         <input type="textbox" name="lot_rel2" id="lr2" class="lr" value="<?php echo $row->lot_rel2; ?>" />   </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Lot Released-3 </b></td>
      <td>
         <input type="textbox" name="lot_rel3" id="lr3" class="lr" value="<?php echo $row->lot_rel3; ?>" />   </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="125"><b>Total Lot Released </b></td>
      <td>
         <input type="textbox" name="total_lot_rel" id="tlrr" class="tlr" value="<?php echo $row->total_lot_rel; ?>" />   </td>
    </tr>
```

Javascript for addition and subtraction:It works nice.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lr').val(0); // reset
    $('.lr,#re').keyup(function () {
    $('.tqty, #totalAmt').val(<?php echo $row->rcv_quantity; ?>);
    $('.tlr,#tlrr').val(<?php echo $row->total_lot_rel; ?>);
    // Loop through all inputs and re-calculate the total
    var total = parseFloat(totalAmt.value);
    var total_lr = parseFloat(tlrr.value);
    $('.lr,#re').each(function () {
    // the "+" before the variable makes sure it's a number instead of a string
    // the "or 0" makes it 0 if it's empty, instead of "undefined"
    var number = +$(this).val() || 0;

    // console.log(number);


    total -= +number; // adds up the numbers
    decimal = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2); 
    // sets the total to 2 decimal places
    });

    //----------------------------
    $('.lr').each(function () {

    var number = +$(this).val() || 0;
    total_lr += +number;

    decimal1 = parseFloat(total_lr).toFixed(2); // sets the total to 2 decimal places
    });
    //--------------------------------
    // Update the total
    $('#totalAmt').val(decimal);
    $('#tlrr').val(decimal1);
    //$('#notRbl1').val(decimal);
    });
});
</script>
```

But not disable those textbox which has value and these textbox also participate addition and subtraction.Javascript textbox disable

```
window.onload = function() {

 if (document.getElementById("lr1").value != null) {
ddocument.getElementById('lr1')
    .setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');  
}
else if (document.getElementById("lr2").value != null) {
ddocument.getElementById('lr2')
    .setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');  
    }
else if (document.getElementById("lr3").value != null) {
ddocument.getElementById('lr3')
    .setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');  
    }
}
```

I want this when lr1 is input it will subtract from totalAmt and and lr1 value show in tlrr. Then when I want to input lr2 then lr1 is disable and only lr2 subtract from totalAmt and it will add tlrr.

Comment: Can you help me about this. Disabling a textbox if it has value and ignored this disabled value in addition and subtraction in jquery. There is any keyword like disable which will disable textbox also value won't count any jquery addition and subtraction?